# How to trigger server side event when testing event-stream using cherrypy.test?

Tags: unit-testing, server-sent-events, cherrypy

When using cherrypy.test to test server sent event streams:

```
class Test_BasicPage(helper.CPWebCase):
        ....
        def test_eventSource(self):
               self.getPage("/updateSSE")
               self.assertBody() # Here I need a hook that can allow me to trigger the event on the server side
```

Is there a best practice when it comes to testing event-stream using helper.CPWebCase? Thanks.